# Select Query using Case When exists

Tags: sql

I have below entries in DB

[image]

I am looking for a query where it first checks the below query and if there are entries then it should fetch me the entries with the second query.

First Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Question  
WHERE question_id = 1 
      AND Type = 'FirstPage'  
      AND Question= 'page1_question' 
      AND Answer = 'page1_answer'
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Question  
WHERE Question_id = 1 
      AND Type = 'FirstPage' 
      AND Question='Page1_question_checkbox' 
      AND Answer = 'page1_answer_checkbox'
```

Can you please let me know how to do this.

I have tried the below query but not working

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM Question 
            WHERE question_id = 1
                AND Type = 'FirstPage'
                AND Question = 'page1_question'
                AND Answer = 'page1_answer'
        ) THEN
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM Question 
            WHERE question_id = 1
                AND Type = 'FirstPage' 
                AND Question= 'Page1_question_checkbox' 
                AND Answer = 'page1_answer_checkbox'
                )
        ELSE
            'Condition is not met.'
    END;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share your simple data and the expected output as text not image, So it can be easy for us to help you

Comment: iam unable to add image.since i doesnt have that many points.

Comment: Please tag only one RDBMS

Comment: Case can not really be used to return multiple columns.  Have you considered just using a self join to the question table where no data will be returned if your criteria are not met?  Do you need an output of 'Condition is not met'?

Comment: A bit odd table design.

Comment: No good idea. Just do that in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question well but the following query returns the records that match the following criterion:

a. question_id = 1
b. type = 'FirstPage'
c. question = 'Page1_question_checkbox'
d. answer = 'page1_answer_checkbox'
e. Exists at least one record with same question id and type as well as the
question and answer as stated in the first criterion

```
SELECT ques.*
FROM   question ques
WHERE  ques.question_id = 1
  AND  ques.type = 'FirstPage'
  AND  ques.question= 'Page1_question_checkbox'
  AND  ques.answer = 'page1_answer_checkbox'
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   question cond
               WHERE  ques.question_id = cond.question_id
                 AND  ques.type = cond.type
                 AND  cond.question = 'page1_question'
                 AND  cond.answer = 'page1_answer')
```

Comment: This one worked @Robert.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether the question has both questions and both answers, we can use the `group by` and `having` clauses :

```
select q.*
from Question q
join (
  select question_id
  from Question
  where question_id = 1
  group by question_id
  having count(case when Type = 'FirstPage' and Question= 'page1_question' and Answer = 'page1_answer' then 1 end) = 1
       and count(case when Type = 'FirstPage' and Question= 'Page1_question_checkbox' and Answer = 'page1_answer_checkbox' then 1 end) = 1
) s on s.question_id = q.question_id
```

Tested on oracle and mysql https://dbfiddle.uk/ty54aglz